# How do I echo message at the top of the form, after performing insertion, update and delete on same page, while using header("location:$url");

Tags: php, session, header

How do I echo message at the top of the form, after performing insertion, update and delete on same page, while using `header("location:$url");`

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){

            if(isset($_GET['id1'])){
            $Id1 = base64_decode($_GET['id1']);
            
            $qry = "SELECT Name,Description,Role FROM cms WHERE id='$Id1'";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
            $res1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $uname = $res1['Name'];
            $address = $res1['Description'];
            $role1 = $res1['Role'];
            }
        }     
        if(isset($_POST['update']))
        { 
            if(isset($_GET['id1']))
                {
                
                $id1=base64_decode($_GET['id1']);
                $uname = $_POST['uname'];
                $address =  $_POST['address'];
                $role =  $_POST['role'];
                $qry2 = "UPDATE cms SET Name ='$uname', Description = '$address',Role='$role' WHERE 
                id='$id1'";
                $res2 = mysqli_query($conn,$qry2);
            if(mysqli_error($conn))
            {
                echo "error";
             } else {
                $_SESSION['success'] = "Record Updated Successfully!";
               header("location:admin.php");
            }                    
        } 
    }                              

?>
```

I tried running the above code in HTML snippet to display the echo message on my webpage but it does not echo the message with header tag

Comment: You are just echoing the “error” nothing else in your code.

Comment: it will echo "error" if the mysqli_query for UPDATE  doesn't execute, but here the UPDATE query is executing so it should go to the else part and shud execute the $_SESSION['success'] code. I have not said here in this code, but I am echoing $_SESSION['success'] using session_start(); I also cud not unset the session on the same page Hence I am figuring out how to echo that $_SESSION part after the header refresh

Comment: Can you share that other code as well?
You can also use query string when redirecting and display message from query string as an alternate solution.

Comment: I am echoing that above the hr tag                                                                          
        <div class="container">
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
     echo "<p>".$_SESSION['success']."</p>";
     unset($_SESSION['success']);
        } ?>

 <h3>Task Assignment</h3>

    <hr>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                <label for="uname">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php if (!empty($uname)) echo $uname ?>" class="form-control">       
       </div>